# Why is the exit() method manually being called while it is unreachable anyways because of header("location: ...")?

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-redirect

As the title states: why are people calling the `exit()` method after a `header("...")` while that method is unreachable anyways? Or is it reachable and is it important to add it?

Example:

```
header("location: $url");
exit();
```

Comment: So that it doesn't execute the rest of the code on the page.

Comment: if `header()` stopped executing the rest of the code, then you'd only ever be able to send one header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `header()`call does not stop the execution of your script immediately. If you redirect but you don't call  `exit()`, then the code is always executed.

To demonstrate this issue, you can consider the following code:

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'I was executed, YAY!');
```

It will redirect you to Google, but will also output the text in `file.txt`. It proves that `header()` calls don't necessarily stop the script execution. You should always use `exit()` to make sure that the script isn't executed further.

Comment: +1 for the example, I have to do some serious edits then in my web application!

Answer (score 2):

The php interpreter only sends a header to the browser when process the `header()` command. It means it sends the `Location:...` to the browser but continues to process the php file.
So you need the `exit()` to stop processing the remaining file.

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` function does not terminate your application. Any code which follows a `header()` call, even to `header("Location: …")`, is still executed; its output just happens to be invisible to a web browser. As such, calling `exit()` following a redirect is definitely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because `header` sends an HTTP header but does not stop the execution of the application, but `exit` is actually telling the PHP interpreter to exit the application, so it's a bit of a race condition. If you told the application to wait about 5 seconds before calling `exit` it would most likely not execute, depending on the speed of the browser to respond to the HTTP header.